# Problem using NetworkRender and SSL

Tags: python

we have a "Blender Farm" with a master and a few slaves. Now we try to use SSL. I configured the path of the certificate and the key, but the Blender-Master crashes with the following error:

```
read blend: /home/renderuser/blender/master-int.blend
Error: wrap_socket() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sock'
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/renderuser/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.74/scripts/addons/netrender/client.py", line 367, in render
raise e
File "/home/renderuser/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.74/scripts/addons/netrender/client.py", line 362, in render
self.render_master(scene)
File "/home/renderuser/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.74/scripts/addons/netrender/client.py", line 383, in render_master
key_path=netsettings.key_path)
File "/home/renderuser/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.74/scripts/addons/netrender/master.py", line 1165, in runMaster
ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23,
TypeError: wrap_socket() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sock'
location: <unknown location>:-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

On all systems is CentOS7 and Blender 2.74 installed. Unfortunately I am not a python specialist. Maybe there is an error in the python-script master.py? Has anyone experience with Network Rendering and SSL?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution by myself. There are missing argumets in the python-script netrender/master.py.

This thread was helpful:
https://developer.blender.org/rBA8b56ce969db281579bf35000ef7b20a8d9590dbb

I reported a bug here:
https://developer.blender.org/T50475